# Bound of size $X\subset \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies $X+X=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

(Sorry for my poor english skill..)

Let $N$ be a large integer and the set $X$ be the subset of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. For two sets $A$ and $B$, we define
\begin{equation}
A+B:=\{a+b  : a\in A, b\in B\}.
\end{equation}
Is there a bound of size X that satisfies $X+X=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Obviously $m(m+1)/2\geqslant N$ where $m=|X|$. On the other hand, therу exist such $X$ of size roughly $C\sqrt{N}$ (take $s=[\sqrt{N}]$ and $X=\{0,1,\dots,s-1,s,2s,3s,\dots,s^2,s(s+1)\}$.)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A066063

Comment: @Bullet51: Note that A066063 is only a related sequence, not the same one, since the OP is concerned with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Surely, the sequence works as an upper bound.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(N)$ denote the size of the smallest $X \subseteq \mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z$ such that $X+X= \mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z$. As Fedor Petrov pointed out above, 
$$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{N} \leq f(N) \leq 2 \sqrt{N}.$$

As far as I am aware, the precise value of the multiplicative constant is not known. There is a fairly recent paper of [Jia and Shen](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/15M1013237?af=R&mobileUi=0) which improves the upper bound to $f(N) \leq (\sqrt{3} +o(1)) \sqrt N$.